# Express Module in node exports an function or an object

Tags: node.js, express

While using express in node we write `app = express()` which shows that express module exports only a function i.e. `module.exports=function(){}` something like that but at the same time for using static files we do something like `app.use(express.static())` which shows that express module exports an object with static function as one feature. Can someone explain how this contradicting this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript. You can pass them around, and you can effectively treat them as objects:

```
function express() {}

express.static = function () {};
express.SOME_CONSTANT = 42;
```

The above example allows consumers to invoke `express()` as a function, or to reference any property of `express`, one of which happens to be another function.

You may have come across this concept before with built-in methods of the [function prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) such as `call`, `apply` or `bind`:

```
function express() {}

const boundExpress = express.bind(someContext);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton sir :)